# TypeScript 'this' type behaves differently from using the class type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm refactoring some old code in our project and I have a problem with TS treating `this` type differently than any other type. I don't want to describe the use case in the project in full detail as it's pretty complex, but I've prepared minimal example that illustrates the problem. [Link to TS playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBLANjYUDCEAdgCYYwbECGWWiAPAMoQCuUAxsADRyGnmUiAPjgBeOAAUM7ANb0AUHDjM2nLorgBvOAG0A0nAxE4M4IggAzZaw7AAugC5rq4PrtxQuUgGdexMhTEcAD8cAZORMAAbnhwAL46puZWKrZ28kIA3PLy7FhU3r4AgkQYALZUgUT0ACoimhrsxN4wUCzsMNAAFDBUUADmwDBONTxgUBBg3k6YOHh8AYI0dLU8RCxlAEZ4QgCUWhpKTUTeEFjAAHRYEP09fYMwYxNTu9lKcfIfufmFcADymwAVsAOgclCAxHAAAxvOBEKhlVDiADkuBayNhFny-UhFho3mA2UazVa7U6UC6%20waSiOJLgVFKZUhkQA7nASuVKoIegALDDeHjaEBOKHxV5wAD0ErgTTKYGwsTwEygTiKAw2wCI8EsCGQqGRQpFmXiyMMviIEHgBW8GH68M25wQEDgYD6CKGsR1SBQcGRs1wBH8AmotAYMD5ArhG22UCEyIuhxldIZ5QATMzgGyORUqrz%20fTfADgR1BXBhdCxcapQgI2a4CzyDzWPAlRBfAU4AADcP8zt19gFXAkJ3-IEgmAaD4fIA)

```js
export type FilterConditionally<Source, Condition> = Pick<
  Source,
  { [K in keyof Source]: Source[K] extends Condition ? K : never }[keyof Source]
>;

class Animation<T> {
  constructor(target: T, props: FilterConditionally<T, number>) {
    console.log(target, props);
  }
}

class Object {
  x = 0;
  name = 'test';
  flag = false;

  constructor() {
    const anim = new Animation(this, { x: 0 }); // compiler error: Argument of type '{ x: 0; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterConditionally<this, number>'.
    const anim2 = new Animation(this as Object, { x: 0 }); // this is without erros as `this` is casted to Object
  }
}
```

We have a generic `Animation` class that takes 2 arguments - target object and props object that takes properties of the target object you want to animate over (but only numbers as you cannot animate over other types). If the `Animation` is generic over `Object`, the typing works and compiler doesn't complain (and correct properties are hinted to the user), but if the `Animation` is generic over `this` type, the typing is broken and I don't really understand why and how to fix it (or if it is fixable). Using `this` as target is valid and common usecase and requiring users to cast it to `Object` with `as` is not reasonable as we are building a library for others to use.

Could someone please explain to me why it's behaving like that and if it can be fixed?

Comment: I understand this could be because of how the 'polymorphic this' type will bind to subsequent generics.  For example, `new Animation(this, { x: 0 })` will force `{x:0}` to be of type `FilterConditionally<this, number>`, but here `this` is no longer referring to an `Object`.   One solution is to bind the generic type yourself with `const anim = new Animation<Object>(this, { x: 0 });`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But forcing users of that class to do that is non-intuitive (and I'm binding the type in the example but with the `as` keyword). Correct type should just be inferred by the compiler in this case.

Comment: It is better to use `CustomObject` instead  of `Object`, because `Object` is built in constructor. Is it possible to use `new CustomObject` instead of `this` ?